# React Router not working when I deploy my app in a folder inside my domain

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created a react app, using viteJS. And I'm using the latest version of the react-router, I followed [this tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial). This app is working fine when I run local, but when deployed to the server I'm getting this error: `Error: No route matches URL "/field-logger/"`

`field-logger` is the folder in my domain where I'm hosting my app. I actually host many other apps that were created with create-react-app and using the previous version of the react-router and they are all working. My problem is with this one.

These are my routes, and the project is set just like the tutorial above.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <BaseLayout />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <LogbooksPage />,
            },
            {
                path: "/logbook/:logbookId",
                element: <LogbookPage />,
            },
            {
                path: "settings",
                element: <SettingsPage />,
            },
            {
                path: "dx-cluster",
                element: <DXClusterPage />,
            }
        ]
    }
]);
```

What am I missing for this to work?

This is my build script (viteJS): `tsc && vite build --base=/field-logger/`. `field-logger` is the folder inside my ftp where I'm putting the app. The `base` option is described [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html). I also tried the `homepage` in the `packages.json`

The source is public and can be [found here](https://github.com/andrekgb/field-logger).

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specially for this version

Inside your package.json

Set the homepage entry with your prefix.

[Here is the doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#basename)

**Extract** :

> The basename of the app for situations where you can't deploy to the
> root of the domain, but a sub directory.

```
createBrowserRouter(routes, {
    basename: "/app",
});
```

So in your src/routes/router.tsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <BaseLayout />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <LogbooksPage />,
            },
            {
                path: "/logbook/:logbookId",
                element: <LogbookPage />,
            },
            {
                path: "settings",
                element: <SettingsPage />,
            },
            {
                path: "dx-cluster",
                element: <DXClusterPage />,
            }
        ]
    }
], {
   basename: '/field-logger'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It didn't work yet. I have created the app with Vitejs, not create React app. But I reacted another one with create react app and migrated the code and did as you said. Didn't work yet

Comment: Source is here if you'd like to see it: https://github.com/andrekgb/field-logger

Comment: Here we go, there's an update, it really should work this time ;-)

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! It's hosted here =] https://ve2zdx.com/field-logger
Now I just gotta code all the other features =]

Answer (score 0):

your source code doesn't contain a `/field-logger` folder so if you pass the `--base` flag, all your static assets will have invalid `src` and `link` attributes. You can confirm this by checking some files in your `/dist` directory (the default directory which gets created when you build to obtain static assets).
You can resort to previous syntax of `react-router-dom` package. You will have to refactor your code a little bit for that.

Edit: The base flag 'appends' to your root. If your root folder name is already `/field-logger` then by passing `--base=/field-logger/` you are saying that there is a `/field-logger/field-logger` folder and go check that out for my static assets.